# How to show discontinuity of a complex function at given points?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be defined by $f(z)=\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}e^{i arg_\alpha(z)/2}$ where $arg_{\alpha}(z)$ is the angle in $(\alpha,\alpha+2\pi]$ and $A=\{z\in \mathbb C: z=te^{i\alpha}, t\ge 0\}$, how to show the discontinuity of $f$ at $z\in A$? Any help to understand the problem?

Is the set $A$ a bunch cut or a set of bunch points?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the complex square root'?.  The statement is correct only if you choose square roots in a particular way. If you use the principle logarithm to define square roots then the statement you have made is false.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for pointing that out. I mean $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ is defined by $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: That is a meaningless definition. every complex number has two square roots so $\sqrt z$ is not  a well defined function.

Answer (score 0):

If you define $\sqrt {re^{it}}$ as $re^{it/2}$  when $0<t\leq 2\pi$ and take $\alpha =0$ then the statement is correct and it can be proved by showing that square root of $1+\frac i n$ tends to $1$ whereas square root of $1-\frac i n$ tends to $-1$. For other values of $\alpha$ you have to take $\alpha <t \leq 2\pi +\alpha $ instead of $0<\alpha \leq 2\pi$. In other words you haev to rotate $1\pm \frac i n$ by angle $\alpha$.

Comment: What is the set $A$?